# Python - Lista completa de cada escritor, juntamente com o acrónimo de cada pessoa (primeira letra do nome e do apelido)

Tags: string, python-3.x, lista

Com base na lista de escritores abaixo descrita, tenho que criar manualmente uma lista em que cada elemento é uma lista de dois elementos, **nome** e **apelido**.

Eis a lista:

```
escritores = [['Pedro', 'Tamen'], ['Almeida', 'Garrett'], ['Camilo', 'Pessanha'], ['Almada', 'Negreiros'], ['Ibn', 'Bassam'], ['Antonio', 'Aleixo'], ['Ricardo', 'Reis'], ['Mario', 'Sá-Carneiro'], ['Mario', 'Cesariny'], ['Luis', 'Camões'], ['Miguel', 'Torga'], ['Natália', 'Correia'], ['Tolentino', 'Mendonça']]
 Os elementos referenciam-se do seguinte modo:
```

escritores [0][0] = 'Pedro', e escritores [0][1] = 'Tamen'

Lista de escritores

*Pedro Tamen*

*Almeida Garrett*

*Camilo Pessanha*

*Almada Negreiros*

*Ibn Bassam*

*Antonio Aleixo*

*Ricardo Reis*

*Mario Sá-Carneiro*

*Mario Cesariny*

*Luis Camões*

*Miguel Torga*

*Natália Correia*

*Tolentino Mendonça*

O que pretendo é imprimir no ecran o nome completo de cada escritor, juntamente com o acrónimo de cada pessoa (primeira letra do nome e do apelido; PT para Pedro Tamen).

PT Pedro Tamen

…

…

O meu código:

```
escritores = [['Pedro', 'Tamen'], ['Almeida', 'Garrett'], ['Camilo', 'Pessanha'], ['Almada', 'Negreiros'], ['Ibn', 'Bassam'], ['Antonio', 'Aleixo'], ['Ricardo', 'Reis'], ['Mario', 'Sá-Carneiro'], ['Mario', 'Cesariny'], ['Luis', 'Camões'], ['Miguel', 'Torga'], ['Natália', 'Correia'], ['Tolentino', 'Mendonça']]
#print(escritores)

#letra = escritores[1:4]
#escritores [0][0] = 'Pedro', e escritores [0][1] = 'Tamen'

print (escritores[:] [:])
```

Não estou a ser suficientemente inteligente para sair disto!!

Alguma ajuda por favor!?

Obrigado,

Comment: você está muito perto não desista! você só precisa de um ´for´ loop! para percorrer cada item da lista!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se já tens a lista de escritores, para imprimires o nome completo e o acrónimo de cada podes fazer:

```
escritores = [['Pedro', 'Tamen'], ['Almeida', 'Garrett'], ['Camilo', 'Pessanha'], ['Almada', 'Negreiros'], ['Ibn', 'Bassam'], ['Antonio', 'Aleixo'], ['Ricardo', 'Reis'], ['Mario', 'Sá-Carneiro'], ['Mario', 'Cesariny'], ['Luis', 'Camões'], ['Miguel', 'Torga'], ['Natália', 'Correia'], ['Tolentino', 'Mendonça']]
for nome, apel in escritores: # unpacking de cada elemento da lista, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967632/unpacking-extended-unpacking-and-nested-extended-unpacking
    print('{} {}, {}{}'.format(nome, apel, nome[0], apel[0]))
```

Output:

```
Pedro Tamen, PT
Almeida Garrett, AG
Camilo Pessanha, CP
Almada Negreiros, AN
Ibn Bassam, IB
Antonio Aleixo, AA
Ricardo Reis, RR
Mario Sá-Carneiro, MS
Mario Cesariny, MC
Luis Camões, LC
Miguel Torga, MT
Natália Correia, NC
Tolentino Mendonça, TM
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/PapayawhipCourageousArea)

Comment: Nem sei com agradecer. Obrigado

Comment: De nada @JoaoPeixotoFernandes, estamos aqui para isso, todos temos dúvidas